# Помощь в позиционировании с помощью флексов одного блока в другом

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: url(img/Layer%200.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
}





/*Shop*/

    
.shop{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    padding: 45px 215px 0 190px ;
    height: 690px;
    width: 1280px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}    

.produkts{
    width: 255px;
    height: 260px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #3cc395;
}

.produkts img{

}
        
/*End Shop*/
```

```html
<!--Shop block-->
    <div class="shop">
    <div class="produkts">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
    <h2>BRANDED SHOE</h2>
    <h2>$300</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="produkts">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
    <h2>BRANDED SHOE</h2>
    <h2>$300</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="produkts">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
    <h2>BRANDED SHOE</h2>
    <h2>$300</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="produkts">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
    <h2>BRANDED SHOE</h2>
    <h2>$300</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="produkts">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
    <h2>BRANDED SHOE</h2>
    <h2>$300</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="produkts">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
    <h2>BRANDED SHOE</h2>
    <h2>$300</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
<!--End Shop block-->
```

Как спозиционировать элементы товара, по центру примерно так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: url(img/Layer%200.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
}

/*Shop*/

.shop{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    padding: 45px 215px 0 190px ;
    height: 690px;
    width: 1280px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}    

.produkts{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;

    width: 255px;
    height: 260px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #3cc395;
}

.produkts img{

}
        
/*End Shop*/
```

```html
<!--Shop block-->
<div class="shop">
    <div class="produkts">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
    <h2>BRANDED SHOE</h2>
    <h2>$300</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="produkts">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
    <h2>BRANDED SHOE</h2>
    <h2>$300</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="produkts">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
    <h2>BRANDED SHOE</h2>
    <h2>$300</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="produkts">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
    <h2>BRANDED SHOE</h2>
    <h2>$300</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="produkts">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
    <h2>BRANDED SHOE</h2>
    <h2>$300</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="produkts">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
    <h2>BRANDED SHOE</h2>
    <h2>$300</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End Shop block-->
```

Comment: А как мне уменьшить расстояние между названием товара и ценой?

Comment: `justify-content: start;`, если еще нужно уменьшить, то через `margin` у `h2`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы уменьшить расстояние,просто добавь "название товара" и  "цену" В один общий блок и выравняй его flex-ами 
пример:

```
<div>
<h2>Название товара</h2>
<h2>Цена<h2>
<div>
стили css к этому блоку:
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justifay Сам подгонишь.
```

ну или можешь marginami но я так понимаю тебе нужно flex